# The application area of nodal and mesh analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm a beginner in electrical engineering.
Are nodal and mesh analysis applicable EVEN in wye or delta networks?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is applicable in any circuit where Ohm and Kirchhoff laws are applicable.

Comment: I'm not sure why you imagine they would not be. Those techniques are quite general. They do have boundaries where they become "difficult" but those are non-linear cases.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good old Ohm doesn't care/matter. Got five diodes and a transistor? Fine, currents flowing through a node still add up to zero!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this is *everywhere*, and it will be the fundamental, and apply to anything – up till you start dealing with quantum effects (where charges might not need go the route your boundary conditions dictate) or with magnetism or radio waves (where "current" is a bit less meaningful) – and even there, we often use models that allow us to use these tools to work with these things that are not actually electrical circuits!

Anything that you can see on a circuit board (and if it's radio frequency, anything where your circuit board is significantly shorter than the wavelength) is defined by it. The simulators, the models and our own understanding of how electronics work are based on it.

They apply *especially* in wye or delta networks – you'll see that when you understand the math that defines their relation. Good luck with your studies!